# publish project in vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a project that builds and is publish correctly before I moved to Windows 10. After I updated to Windows 10 I can build and test my project but I cannot publish my MVC project. It gives me the following error which I do not understand:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I added `Microsoft.Web.Deployment` from nuget but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following will solve your problem

1. Downloaded Web Deploy 3.5, from http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy
2. install complete package
3. Then open your project in VS 2013.
4. Publish your project.

Thanks